# Connecting my WP site to Facebook using social-media-auto-publish

Tags: wordpress, facebook

Sorry for this rather basic question, but we have the "social-media-auto-publish" plugin installed on our village website, and it was publishing to Facebook absolutely fine a while back.  But then some new procedures on Facebooks end came into play, and it doesn't appear that the posting is working anymore.  I have asked Facebook, but they simply said that they cannot help, and I should ask here instead.

When I try to connect the app, I get the below message back

> Invalid Scopes: pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_posts. This
> message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore
> these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid
> permissions at:
> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

Now, we are a village (not a business) but am I right in thinking that only a business has access to these capabilities now?  Or is 'Business Verification' actually a much more open thing for non-businesses to use?

Thanks for any advice you can give,
Dan

Comment: You only need business verification, if your app is going to access data owned by other businesses. If you just want to post to your own pages, then individual verification should be enough.

Comment: Any thoughts on why I would get that error in which case, or am I better speaking to the plugin team if this is not a Facebook issue? Thanks

Comment: Both `pages_read_engagement` and `pages_manage_posts` would need business verification though, according to docs. Could be that is a new thing. Who you’d need to talk to about this, depends on whether you are using your own app id, or whether this is done via an app id belonging to the plugin developer.

Comment: It's my own app ID, so going through the steps to somehow connect this non business use into a business account is required still. Feels odd to have to do that tbh, but from what I have read, this appears the only way